# How do I set user level flags for Grid Engine bsub command?

Tags: sungridengine

I am running GridEngine (GE 6.2u5) jobs from a command line. For example,
    qsub echo "Hello"

But I get this error,
    Unable to read script file because of error: error opening echo: No such file or directory

The workaround is easy, use the -b y flag. I'd like to create an SGE properties file in my home directory which will set '-y' to be the default. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add your option, you can edit the file "sge_request". It allows you to set the default options that will be added to any requests you will submit.
This file is situated in : SGE_ROOT/CELL_NAME/common/sge_request

For more information, check the documentation : http://gridscheduler.sourceforge.net/htmlman/htmlman5/sge_request.html